# Python Script to SSH into a VM throwing a 'Resource Temporarily Unavailable' Error

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, pytest

bit of a newb here I am in the process of writing some pytest Python scripts to test a UI, one of my tests is to test SSH logins and to login to a running VM.Problem is everything I try is throwing a 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error.

My current script is using subprocess, I have also tried Paramiko and get the same result. I have confirmed port 22 is open and I do have access (In fact from the terminal in Visual Code I can SSH to the VM manually) so, im at a bit of a loss at the moment I added some prints to make sure im getting the right IP, and password and all are correct. Can anyone help? Apologies if this is a silly question i`m learning python by creating these tests.

My script is:

```
from api_v1 import api
import requests
import pytest
import time
import config
import json
import subprocess
import paramiko
from list_config import resetpassword, listpublicipaddresses, listnetwork, is_vm_running

def test_login():
    api_key = config.api_key
    secret_key = config.secret_key
    base_url = config.base_url

    api = api(api_key=api_key, secret_key=secret_key, base_url=base_url, return_json=True)

    network_info = listnetwork()
    network_id = network_info[0]
    password = resetpassword()
    ip_addresses = listpublicipaddresses(network_id)
    ssh_output = None
    
    for ip in ip_addresses:
        ip_address = ip['ip']
        
        if is_vm_running(ip_address):
            ssh_command = [
                'ssh',
                '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
                '-l', 'ubuntu',
                ip_address,
                'ls -l'
            ]
            ssh_process = subprocess.Popen(ssh_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            ssh_output, ssh_error = ssh_process.communicate()
            ssh_output = ssh_output.decode()
            ssh_error = ssh_error.decode()

            if ssh_process.returncode == 0:
                print(f"\nSSH Output: {ip_address}")
                print(ssh_output)
            else:
                print(f"\nSSH Error: {ip_address}")
                print(ssh_error)
        else:
            print(f"\nVM is not running: {ip_address}")
            print(ssh_output)
```

Thanks

tried using paramiko instead of subprocess
I can ssh into the VM and an nmap scan shows port 22 open

I expect the script to login to the VM and show the result in the result in the terminal